# Glide Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot obtain size for recycled Bitmap: android.graphics.Bitmap@a4f3bcf[896x157] ARGB_8888

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I have an activity with a recycler view with some backgrounds.

Sometimes when scroll the recyclerview and press back button I get this error.

I have two types of background(one is blurred).

To load the normal background I use:

```
fun AppCompatImageView.loadImage(resId: Int) {
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, resId))
            .into(this)
}
```

To load the blurred background I use:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
  .applyDefaultRequestOptions(RequestOptions().override(backgroundWidth, backgroundHeight))
  .asBitmap()
  .load(R.drawable.card_dog_placeholder)
  .into(object : SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                                override fun onResourceReady(bitmap: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                                    cardYouAreHeroBackgroundImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap.blurRenderScript(mContext, CARD_BG_RADIUS))
                                }
                            })

fun Bitmap.blurRenderScript(context: Context, radius: Float): Bitmap {
    val rs = RenderScript.create(context)
    val blurredBitmap = copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)

    val input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, blurredBitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_FULL, Allocation.USAGE_SHARED)
    val output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.type)

    val script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs))
    script.setInput(input)

    script.setRadius(radius)
    script.forEach(output)
    output.copyTo(blurredBitmap)
    return blurredBitmap
}
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity
>   {com.yourpackage/com.yourpackage.DashboardActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot obtain size for recycled
>   Bitmap: android.graphics.Bitmap@a4f3bcf[896x157] ARGB_8888 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4383)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4401)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(Unknown Source:0) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) Caused
>   by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot obtain size for recycled
>   Bitmap: android.graphics.Bitmap@a4f3bcf[896x157] ARGB_8888 at
>   com.bumptech.glide.util.Util.getBitmapByteSize(Util.java:78) at
>   com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.UnitBitmapDecoder$NonOwnedBitmapResource.getSize(UnitBitmapDecoder.java:49)
>   at
>   com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineResource.getSize(EngineResource.java:60)
>   at
>   com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.cache.LruResourceCache.getSize(LruResourceCache.java:42)
>   at
>   com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.cache.LruResourceCache.getSize(LruResourceCache.java:13)
>   at com.bumptech.glide.util.LruCache.put(LruCache.java:124) at
>   com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.cache.LruResourceCache.put(LruResourceCache.java:13)
>   at
>   com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.Engine.onResourceReleased(Engine.java:326)
>   at
>   com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineResource.release(EngineResource.java:112)
>   at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.Engine.release(Engine.java:286) at
>   com.bumptech.glide.request.SingleRequest.releaseResource(SingleRequest.java:345)
>   at
>   com.bumptech.glide.request.SingleRequest.clear(SingleRequest.java:324)
>   at
>   com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestTracker.clearRemoveAndMaybeRecycle(RequestTracker.java:73)
>   at
>   com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestTracker.clearRemoveAndRecycle(RequestTracker.java:60)
>   at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.untrack(RequestManager.java:623)
>   at
>   com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.untrackOrDelegate(RequestManager.java:591)
>   at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.clear(RequestManager.java:579) at
>   com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.onDestroy(RequestManager.java:323)
>   at
>   com.bumptech.glide.manager.ActivityFragmentLifecycle.onDestroy(ActivityFragmentLifecycle.java:65)
>   at
>   com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment.onDestroy(SupportRequestManagerFragment.java:194)
>   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroy(Fragment.java:2585)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1559)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1752)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1821)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3251)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:3242)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy(FragmentController.java:265)
>   at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:390)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(AppCompatActivity.java:209)
>   at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:7208) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1249)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4370)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4401)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5(Unknown Source:0)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1649) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Any idea?

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems related to bitmap recycle. I replaced bitmap.recycle() with Glide.get(this).getBitmapPool().put( bitmap ) but it still happens. Have you solved? I'm using Glide 4.6.1, and you?

Comment: Mi issue was related because I was blurring a view, to blur a view I use set drawing cache enable view. And after that I disable the cache and crash. So the solution was use other method to get the view as bitmap.

Comment: Hi, @AndroidRuntimeException. By any chance do you remember how exactly you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there are no statements like below in your code :

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).clear(target);
Glide.get(getApplicationContext()).getBitmapPool().clearMemory();
```

From docs, getBitmapPool() returns the `{@link com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.bitmap_recycle.BitmapPool}` used to temporarily store `{@link android.graphics.Bitmap}` so they can be reused to avoid garbage collections.

Usually this error happens when any bitmap recycling happens specially when the bitmap is already recycled. So in case `getBitmapPool()` is needed better to wrap inside a `if` check `!bitmap.isRecycled()`